# How do I append a dictionary item to a pre-existing dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a .csv file containing tweets and their sentiment polarity. Using DictReader, I see each row in the file in the format:

```
Sentiment: '0', SentimentText: 'xyz'
```

Now I want to add each row of the file to a pre-existing dictionary such that the structure of the dictionary at the end is:

```
{{Sentiment: '0', SentimentText: 'xyz'},
 {Sentiment: '1', SentimentText: 'abc'}...#so on until eof}
```

Is there any way that this is possible?

EDIT: So far, this is what I have achieved. This basically makes a list of dictionaries:

```
dataset = []
with open('SentimentAnalysisDataset.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    count = 1
    for row in reader:
        data = [{'Text': row['SentimentText'], 'Polarity': row['Sentiment']}]
        tuple = {str(count): data}
        count = count + 1
        dataset.append(tuple)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression?rq=1

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @Mominaathar, this is not the correct structure of a dictionary. Are you sure you don't intend it to be a list?

Comment: @Bharel, basically I want to append to a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: @fledgling alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
{{Sentiment: '0', SentimentText: 'xyz'},
 {Sentiment: '1', SentimentText: 'abc'}...#so on until eof}
```

Is not a valid dictionary structure. If you wish to use a list, this will work:

```
[{Sentiment: '0', SentimentText: 'xyz'},
 {Sentiment: '1', SentimentText: 'abc'}...#so on until eof]
```

Otherwise, you're probably looking for a structure like this:

```
{'0': 'xyz',
 '1': 'abc',
 ...}
```

In order to do that, you should update the existing dictionary like so:

```
existing_dict = {'0': 'xyz',
                 '1': 'abc'}

existing_dict[row['Sentiment']] = row['SentimentText']

# OR
new_dict = {row['Sentiment']: row['SentimentText'],
            ... # For all sentiments in file
            }
existing_dict.update(new_dict)
```